# Group by day from a certain hour of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

SQLServer 2008r2. I have a table which is populated with a record at 10 mins past every hour of every day.  Every hour the job is run it also enters 48 records which represent a forecast of what is likely to happen for the next 48 hours.  Note - Just before it enters the 48 hour forecast it deletes the forecast which was entered last time.  So although it enters a 48 hour forecast every hour there is only ever one forecast in the system.  The relevant fields in the table look like this:

```
currentScore       obsDate  
     9         2017-06-22 08:10:00
     9         2017-06-22 07:10:00
     9         2017-06-22 06:10:00
    10         2017-06-22 05:10:00
    ...       ...
```

How can I query this table and group by day from a certain time of day? I would like the day to start at 6am the day before and finish at 6am on the day.  I only need five records from the table, the day, two before and two in the future.  So if its Jun 20 I want June 18, 19, 20, 21 and 22.  Here is the query which gets the correct results by calendar day.

```
SELECT cast(obsDate AS DATE) AS theDate
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN currentScore < 8
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS currentscore_low
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN currentScore >= 8
                AND currentScore < 17
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS currentscore_medium
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN currentScore >= 17
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS currentscore_high
FROM diseaseScores
WHERE siteID = 8315
    AND obsDate >= cast(getdate() - 2 AS DATE)
GROUP BY cast(obsDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY cast(obsDate AS DATE);
```

which returns this result:

```
theDAte       low   med   high
2017-06-18     23    0     0
2017-06-19     22    0     0
2017-06-20     5     19    0
2017-06-21     0     24    0
2017-06-22     0     9     0
```

There is a new requirement to get the same result but the group by and the subsequent counts need to be from 6am to 6am. e.g

the first rec should be from 2017-06-17 06:00am to 2017-06-18 06:00am 
the second rec should be from 2017-06-18 06:00am to 2017-06-19 06:00am 
....etc

How can I do this?  Thanks in advance

UPDATE, I have done two things:

1..introduce Tims idea

2..I also add an extra field 'numOfScores' to show how many hours worth of data
   each line represent

```
    select
        cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date) as theDate,  count(currentScore) as numOfScores, 
        sum(case when currentScore < 8 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_low,
        sum(case when currentScore >= 8 and currentScore < 17
                 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_medium,
        sum(case when currentScore >= 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_high
    from diseaseScores
    where siteID = 8315 and
          obsDate >= cast(getdate() - 2 as date)  
    group by cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date)
    order by cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date);
```

I now get this result:

```
    2017-06-18  5   5   0   0
    2017-06-19  24  23  1   0
    2017-06-20  24  1   23  0
    2017-06-21  24  8   16  0
    2017-06-22  24  1   23  0
    2017-06-23  9   0   9   0
```

This tells me that that there is only 5 hours worth of scores on the 2017-06-18.  I want this first line to be 24 hours worth.   From 6am on the 17th until 6am on the 18th.  This makes me think I am not getting the result I wish

The 23rd only having 9 hours is ok because this is the most recent forecast

UPDATED:

I dont think its easily done in one query (if even possible) so I will just use five queries and specifically state the dates&times to get my outcome.  e.g here are the first two:

```
    select 
      sum(case when currentScore < 9 then 1 else 0 end) as numOfLOWRecs, 
      sum(case when currentScore > 8 and currentScore < 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_medium, 
      sum(case when currentScore >= 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_high 
    from diseaseScores where siteID = 9999 
    and obsDate >= '2017-06-18 06:00' and obsDate < '2017-06-19 06:00'

    select 
      sum(case when currentScore < 9 then 1 else 0 end) as numOfLOWRecs, 
      sum(case when currentScore > 8 and currentScore < 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_medium, 
      sum(case when currentScore >= 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_high 
    from diseaseScores where siteID = 9999 
    and obsDate >= '2017-06-19 06:00' and obsDate < '2017-06-20 06:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

One trick which might work here would be to simply shift each observation *backwards* by 6 hours.  This would shift `2017-06-17 06:00:00` to `2017-06-17 00:00:00`, i.e. now 6am becomes the start of that actual day.

```
select
    cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date) as theDate,  
    sum(case when currentScore < 8 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_low,
    sum(case when currentScore >= 8 and currentScore < 17
             then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_medium,
    sum(case when currentScore >= 17 then 1 else 0 end) as currentscore_high
from diseaseScores
where siteID = 8315 and
      obsDate >= cast(getdate() - 2 as date)  
group by cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date)
order by cast(dateadd(hour, -6, obsDate) as date);
```

Comment: HI @tim since I am grouping by a date data type I can not do this.   The query throws this. The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.  The base table has hourly records therefore I think I need to group by a date data type?

Comment: What is the type of your `obsDate` column?  Is it text?

Comment: diseaseScores.obsDate is a smalldatetime field

Comment: that did make the query run but I dont think its achieving the objective.   I have added to my post to explain this.   Essentially the query is not beginning From 6am on the 17th until 6am on the 18th

Comment: Where do hours even come into play here?  You are casting to date.

Comment: I have just re read your initial comment and realized I mis understood what your trick was.   I see you have just shifted where the day starts by six hours.  Apologies I was not clearer, my big objective was to make the group by day start at 6am the day before

Comment: Hmm...then would shifting each point in time earlier by 18 hours get the job done?

Comment: Yes I think so.  This would result in my first record having a date of 2017-06-17 instead of 2017-06-18 however.    mmmmmm I am unsure if the approach is correct.   The objective is to have five records, the current day, 2 days before and two days after.  Am I trying to put a round peg in a square hole by asking the first record to have the date of the 18th but ask it to get 24 hourly records from 6am on the 17th until 6am on the 18th I wonder?